# MS Access database require newer version

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc, oledb

relating to MS Access, currently i'm suffering with this error every time i open the access accdb file. It says "The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of MS Access".

I am fully understand that based on that i have to update it. But the question is, everything just fine before or never happened before whenever i use this file. So it doesnt make any sense if i have to update.

My assumption so far:

it happened because some error in ODBC connection between access and excel that impact the database. because i use this access to be a database for my excel pivot.

Anyone has same experience?
Your help means a lot for me, because if i can't open this then i have to re-coding from scratch :( (the back up also has the same issue, but other access file can be opened smoothly)

Thank you,

Comment: Check all your references and make sure you use late binding.

Comment: @Fionnuala how can I do the late binding if i can't open my module anymore..  :(

Comment: Have you compacted & repaired? Have you decompiled?

Comment: can't even open the file.. any suggestion ? @Fionnuala

Comment: i just add the /decompile in the shortcut and no luck.. still can't open.. i just realize that i can't open the other file that has similar content.. (double or long data type)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just simply install access 2010.

Yes, it is funny that I am reinstalling the older one but it works..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I was making C# application and it was connected to MS Access DB.
Go to MS Access DB -> File -> Info -> Compact and Repair.
This will downgrade the version and fix this issue.